# Laravel Route namespace problems with the backslash

Tags: laravel

I want to use the Laravel 9 route namespace function and I wonder how to pass the namespace correctly?

```php
Route::as('some.')->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1')->group(function() {
    Route::post('/store', [SomeController::class, 'store'])
        ->name('store');
});
```

I get the following error message:

```
    "message": "Target class [SomeController] does not exist.",
    "exception": "Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException",
```

**Question:** How do I do this properly?

**But this works**

```php
Route::as('some.')->group(function() {
    Route::post('/store', [\App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\SomeController::class, 'store'])
        ->name('store');
});
```

Comment: @devsead I can assure you that it is the right path ;-)

Comment: try `Route::post('/store', 'SomeController@store')->name('store');` and see

Comment: @AbdullaNilam That dont will work because i use subfolders in the default controller folder. `App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1`

Comment: I mean like this `Route::as('some.')->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1')->group(function() {
    Route::post('/store', 'SomeController@store')->name('store');
});
`

Comment: @AbdullaNilam `SomeController@store` this is works in Laravel 9?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to provide the right path to the controller file. For example at the top of the file put this: `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;`

Comment: I can assure you that it is the right path ;-)

Comment: hmm, this error can also appear if you have moved some files through the filesystem and forgot to update paths. It doesn't have to be, but the is not just in web.php file. Can you please try instead of `[SomeController::class, 'store']` this `[App\Full\Path\SomeController::class, 'store']` ?

Answer (score 0):

use it :

```
Route::as('some.')->namespace('Api\V1')->group(function() {
    Route::post('/store', [SomeController::class, 'store'])
        ->name('store');
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately no! Still the same error. But thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a namespace for route,so you should use

```
Route::as('some.')->namespace('App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1')->group(function() {
    Route::post('/store', 'SomeController@store')
        ->name('store');
});
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#routing-namespace-updates